# CSS Display specific area

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Estimate bill</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    * {display:none;}
    page[size="A4"] > * {display: block !important;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <page size="A4">
  Hello world
  </page>
</body>
```

I want to hide the body but I want to show the page element. How can I achieve this please help me. It is a for printing task. I want to print only page element area.

Comment: Did you mean to hide the `<page>` element? For me it's working. What do you mean by "I did'nt want to show the body"? Please specify.

Comment: @shah, Not able to understand what you mean on "hide page but I didn't want to show the body"

Comment: @Govind, he actually is okay with his question. He wants to show <page> content only not anything inside body.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Estimate bill</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    page {
      visibility: visible !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <page size="A4">
    Hello world
  </page>
</body>
```

Comment: This won't work if you have child tags in page - you need to change the * selector to just body

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood what you mean but maybe something like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Estimate bill</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  @media print {
  * {visibility: hidden;}
  page {visibility: visible;}
  .a4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <page size="A4" class="a4">
    Hello world
  </page>
</body>
 </html>
```

I have updated my code for u.

Comment: How it possible it working on your code but not working on my website vsss.co.in/Admin/index.php/Printing/Estimate please use print command.

Comment: @shahrushabh I have updated my code for u. You can check it out.

Comment: @shahrushabh Was my anwser helpful at all as i see you have fixed it some way on your website ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the below .hide css class to whatever elements you want to hide during printing.

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print{
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
}
</style>

<div class="hide"> Some content here... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Estimate bill</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    body{
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    .show {
     visibility: visible;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <page size="A4" class="show">
  Hello world
  </page>
</body>
```